# Jest test does not resolve a promise as it should. Is there a problem with my syntax or logic?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test that a promise resolves and sets state properly according to what the asynchronous call returns. I have been trying to figure out this conundrum for days to almost no avail.

I have tried everything from runAllTimers() to runOnlyPendingTimers() to setTimeout() to simulate the time for the asynchronous call to finish. However, I didn't want to rely on setTimeout(), as that depends on real time instead of fake timers. While the test technically "passes" with setTimeout, I'm not so sure it's valid because when I console-log the state after the setTimeout, it does not update as it should and remains the same after I await the asynchronous call.

```
import 'item' from '../getItem'
jest.useFakeTimers();
it('should update state after fetchItemData fires', async () => {
    const locationOfItem = {
        pathname: '/item/path',
        search: `?id=${itemId}`,
    };
    const props = {
        someStore,
        locationOfItem,
    };
    // The true is here because I use mobx for the store
    const wrapper = createWrapper(ItemDataPage, props, true);

    getItem.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
        Promise.resolve({ item }),
    );

    await wrapper.fetchItemData();
    // jest.runAllTimers();
    // jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    expect(getItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // setTimeout(() => {
    expect(wrapper.state.isLoading).toBe(false);
    expect(wrapper.state.hasError).toBe(false);
    expect(wrapper.state.item).toEqual({ item });

    // }, 1000);
});



    fetchItemData = async () => {
    const { locationOfItem } = this.props;
    const { search } = locationOfItem;
    const id = search.replace('?id=', '');

    try {
        const item = await getItem(id);
    } catch {
        this.state.hasError = true;
    } finally {
        this.setState({isLoading: false, hasError: false, item,});
    }
};
```

The expected results are that all assertions should be as stated in the code snippet. However, when I run this in any context outside of setTimeout(), it fails. Specifically, while getItem gets called properly, and hasError's state is false, the state of isLoading does not get set to false as it should after the promise resolves, and the state of item does not go from an empty object to a populated object as it should. In the method I'm testing, namely fetchItemData(), the method calls a service and sets the state of item to whatever data the service returns, which is an object. The original state of item is always an empty object. In short, isLoading remains true, and item remains an empty object. There is an error message saying "cannot read property "isInStock" of undefined. isInStock is a key inside of the item object, so I would expect that this property is not yet defined because item is still an empty object and does not get updated.

Comment: What does your `ItemDataPage` look like?

Comment: Do you mean the actual view on the browser, the component's render and handler methods, the whole component? What do you mean?

Comment: The entire component. Is it large?

Comment: It's large, but I can at least show the method fetchItemData if that will help.

Comment: `fetchItemData` is being triggered by an event listener right? Show me the component/html element with it and the method it invokes

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to programming. fetchItemData triggers when the component mounts. The user is on one page beforehand, and then when the user clicks on an item, it redirects to the ItemDataPage. So this.fetchItemData() is called inside componentDidMount().

Comment: Where is `getItem` coming from? Is that an api call from a different file, or is it a prop that you forgot to show in your code snippet?

Comment: It's an api call from a different file.

Comment: Looks like you're mocking `getItem` *after* the call to `createWrapper`.  `getItem` is called by `fetchItemData` which is called by `componentDidMount` so you'll want to mock it *before* creating the component with `createWrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

When testing react components, don't test methods. Test the desired implementations inside.

`componentDidMount` automatically runs once you create your `wrapper`. If `fetchItemData` is run inside `componentDidMount`, the test will do it automatically.

Mock the api call. Personally, I find it easier to understand when setting a `return` using `mockMeturnValue` or `mockReturnValueOnce`, as opposed to `mockImplementation`. Ultimately, at your discretion

```
// api test setup
jest.mock('./api/apiFile') // mocks every function in file
const getItem = jest.fn()
getItem.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
  Promise.resolve({ item }),
);
const wrapper = createWrapper(ItemDataPage, props, true);

expect(getItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(wrapper.state.isLoading).toBe(false);
expect(wrapper.state.hasError).toBe(false);
expect(wrapper.state.item).toEqual({ item });
```

You need to mock `const getItem = jest.fn()` before you create your `wrapper`.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, forgot to mention that I did mock the api call at the top below the import and before creating the wrapper, so I guess I'm still stuck...thanks though!